# How to make a Cursive EditView be both secret and named?

Tags: rust, cursive, editview

With this code:

```
.child(EditView::new().set_secret(true).with_name("wlan0-ap0_passwd").fixed_width(16))
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `with_name` exists for unit type `()`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:61
   |
24 |                     .child(EditView::new().set_secret(true).with_name("wlan0-ap0_passwd").fixed_width(16))
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: method `set_secret` modifies its receiver in-place
  --> src/main.rs:24:44
   |
24 |                     .child(EditView::new().set_secret(true).with_name("wlan0-ap0_passwd").fixed_width(16))
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^ this call modifies its receiver in-place
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `(): cursive::View`
           which is required by `(): Nameable`
           `&(): cursive::View`
           which is required by `&(): Nameable`
           `&mut (): cursive::View`
           which is required by `&mut (): Nameable`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `ssid-tui` (bin "ssid-tui") due to 1 previous error
```

The error is telling me that `.set_secret()` is a mutable operation on the EditView and so it must end the chain.  i.e. It doesn't return a View.

I expect that I can add a few lines to create the EditView, assign it to a variable, call `.set_secret('true')` on that variable, and then move that variable into the `.child()` call.

As I have several "secret" EditViews this seems rather long-winded.

Is there an in-line solution to creating "secret" "named" EditViews?